# Recursive function to reverse an arbitrarily nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to write a "simple" recursive function to traverse a tree represented by nested lists.  I have the correct output when I use `print` but I want the result returned in a `list`.

Code

```
def trav(t):
    while len(t) > 1:
        for counter, i in enumerate(t):
            if isinstance(i, list):
                t2 = t.pop(counter)
                trav(t2)
    n=t.pop()
    print(n)
```

Run it

```
tree1 = [1, [2, [4], [5]], [3]]
trav(tree1)
```

Output via print:

```
4
5
2
3
1
```

Desired output via return value:

```
[4, 5, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an accumulator `acc`, aggregate the return value of the recursive call in the loop.

At the end return `acc` + the last popped value (this nicely merges into the base case).

```
def trav(t):
    acc = []
    while len(t) > 1:
        for counter, i in enumerate(t):         
            if isinstance(i, list):
                t2 = t.pop(counter)
                acc += trav(t2)

    n = t.pop()
    return acc + [n]



tree1 = [1, [2, [4], [5]], [3]]
print(trav(tree1))
# [4, 5, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: @coldspeed - Exactly what I needed!  is there a way to do this with `yield`? Just wondering

Comment: @Alex I can't give you a concrete reason (call it programmer's intuition) but I don't believe yield would be idiomatically sound construct for this application.